# Can i use a sparkfun rfid qwiic without an id-xxla?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, rfid

[Sparkfun rfid qwiic](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15191)

[id-20la](https://www.antratek.com/rfid-reader-id-20)

I am using an Arduino UNO R3.

You should assume that i don't know anything. If yes can you give some information about how to do it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not an RFID reader. It just interfaces to an RFID reader. You need an RFID reader to read RFID tags. That Sparkfun board just controls the reader and reads the data from it.